# Python Property, How do I get this to work correctly

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use OO on python to create a nice structured class.  I have an object that all functions from one class will inherit but there are sub functions (getter and setter) that may require one or two additional parameters.

How can I get this type of logic to work correctly.

```
class XYZ(object):
    def __init__(self, cameraId):
        self.cameraId = cameraId;
        self.index = "";

    def get_test(self):
        print "Index: " + self.index + " CameraID: " + self.cameraId;
        return self.cameraId;

    def set_test(self, value, myValue=""):
        self.cameraId = value;
        self.index = myValue;
        return True;

    TEST_XYZ = property(get_test,set_test);
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a property.  set_test is a function, plain and simple, why not use it as a function?  A property with optional elements is confusing.

Comment: Maybe what your are talking about is **kwargs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tuple`-typed values. Note that you don't have to use `;` after your statements...

```
class XYZ(object):
    def __init__(self, cameraId):
        self.cameraId = cameraId
        self.index = ""

    def get_test(self):
        print "Index: " + self.index + " CameraID: " + self.cameraId
        return self.cameraId

    def set_test(self, value):
        # Require value to be a tuple!
        assert(isinstance(value, tuple))

        self.cameraId = value[0]

        try:
            self.index = value[1]

        except IndexError:
            self.index = ""

        return True

    TEST_XYZ = property(get_test, set_test)
```

Comment: I know not to use ; but I'm a programmer in several languages and I dont see why I should stop now considering python is one of the few ive used that doesent like ;

Comment: @Deano: do yourself a favor, and leave off the semicolons.  If you aren't going to use the language properly, why use it at all?